# Is it possible to not show columns with no content in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with the names of 700 investment portfolios in rows and with 70 asset classes as columns.

Each investment portfolio consists of several asset classes as a percentage value. Many portfolios only have 3-5 asset classes, while some have 20.

Now, I want to output each portfolio with only its containing asset classes, so I don't want to display columns that have no contents. I use the SQLite CLI to create the outputs.

Each output should be on one row.

Here is what I do now. I select the columns manually with the asset class the portfolio consists of. I just think that with 700 rows, there might be a smarter way.

```
 SELECT PortfolioName, 
       TotalUSMarket AS "Total US Market", 
       RealEstate AS "REITs",
       InternationalDeveloped AS "International Developed",
       TotalBondMarket AS "Total Bond Market",
       Commodities AS "Commodities"

        FROM PortfolioAllocation
            WHERE PortfolioAllocation.PortfolioNumber_id IN (10);
```

Some outputs have 2 or more rows that need to be output.

Comment: The short answer is No. Since "The result of a SELECT is zero or more rows of data where [*each row has a fixed number of columns*](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)", this is your option.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple funds, and multiple asset classes. Each fund can have multiple assets, and each asset can be used by multiple funds. This is a classic [many to many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29), and is best represented by a multi-table design linking funds and assets using a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), not trying to put everything into one table, as you're seeing.

The idea is to have a table describing funds (Name, date founded, fees, etc.), a table describing asset classes, and a third table that links the two and holds how much of a fund is devoted to that asset class, using the other two table's primary keys as foreign keys.

Example database and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE investment_fund(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE asset_class(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE investment_percentages(
       fund_id INTEGER REFERENCES investment_fund(id),
       asset_id INTEGER REFERENCES asset_class(id),
       percentage REAL,
       PRIMARY KEY(fund_id, asset_id)) WITHOUT ROWID;
CREATE VIEW fund_ownership AS
  SELECT fund_id, if.name AS fund_name, asset_id, ac.name AS asset_name
       , percentage
  FROM investment_fund AS if
  JOIN investment_percentages AS i ON if.id = i.fund_id
  JOIN asset_class AS ac ON i.asset_id = ac.id;
INSERT INTO investment_fund VALUES (1, 'No Bonds Here');
INSERT INTO investment_fund VALUES (2, 'We Do Bonds');
INSERT INTO asset_class VALUES (1, 'Municipal Bond Market');
INSERT INTO asset_class VALUES (2, 'REIT');
INSERT INTO asset_class VALUES (3, 'S&P500 Index');
INSERT INTO investment_percentages VALUES (1, 2, 40);
INSERT INTO investment_percentages VALUES (1, 3, 60);
INSERT INTO investment_percentages VALUES (2, 1, 75);
INSERT INTO investment_percentages VALUES (2, 3, 25);
```

then you can get a list of all the classes owned by a particular fund, and only those, without having to know ahead of time what they are:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM fund_ownership WHERE fund_name = 'We Do Bonds' ORDER BY percentage DESC;
fund_id     fund_name    asset_id    asset_name             percentage
----------  -----------  ----------  ---------------------  ----------
2           We Do Bonds  1           Municipal Bond Market  75.0
2           We Do Bonds  3           S&P500 Index           25.0
```

Comment: The is elegant @Shawn - I have clarified my question to include that output should be on one row.

Comment: @Jon there's `group_concat()`, but anything involving formatting the results is usually better off being done by the calling program.